# Unable to find element after login action

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I am writing some automation using NightWatchJS. I have a simple test scenario where i do following stuff

1. Open Url
2. Login
3. Verify elements
4. Verify Iframe Elements

I have simple login page with submit button. The inner page, after login, has iframe as well. As soon as the login action success, the textfield in the iframe is focused with javascript.

My NightWatch test code

```
module.exports = {
  before: function(browser) {
    console.log("Setting up...");
    browser
      .maximizeWindow()
  },

  after : function(browser) {
    browser
      .end()
    console.log("Closing down...");
  },

  'Check Form Elements' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .url("siteurl") 
      .waitForElementVisible("body", 1000)
      .waitForElementPresent('#email', 10000)
      .setValue('#email','me@a5his.com')
      .waitForElementPresent('#password', 10000)
      .setValue('#password', 'encrypted')
      .submitForm('#login_form', function(result){
        console.log(result)
      })
      .pause(5000)
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 10000)
      .waitForElementVisible('li.active', 5000)
      .assert.containsText('li.active', "Home")
      .assert.elementPresent('#iframeone')
      .frame('iframeone')
        .waitForElementVisible('.wi-wrap', 5000)
        . assert.containsText('header h1', 'Messages')
  }
};
```

This test passes till form submission after that it fails saying

```
Timed out while waiting for element <body> to be present for 10000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: not found
```

I am using Chrome 50, ChromeDriver 2.21.371459, OS X - El Capitan.
I have attached my selenium details below.

[image: Selenium Details]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is your page redirect after successfully login ?

Can you try this :

```
  browser
  .url("siteurl") 
  .waitForElementVisible('#email', 10000,false)
  .setValue('#email','me@a5his.com') 
  .setValue('#password', 'encrypted')
  .click('#login_form')
  .waitForElementVisible('li.active', 5000,false)
  .verify.containsText('li.active', "Home")
  .verify.elementPresent('#iframeone')
  .frame('#iframeone')
  .waitForElementVisible('.wi-wrap', 5000,false)
  .verify.containsText('header h1', 'Messages')
```

Rememeber if the frame id is missing or null, the server should switch to the page's default content. So better the selector should be like below to make sure it will be there and unique .

```
'input[name=username]',
'button[name=login]',
'iframe[class=iframeone]'
```

Edit 1: For the element 'body' ,you should check 'present or not' instead of 'visible or not'

try `waitForElementPresent('body',5000,false)`

instead of

`waitForElementVisible('body',5000,false)`

Comment: Hey Bao, there is no any problem with login. I can see all the elements rendered in page but test fails as it never find such element.

Comment: So can you add one more argument for waitForElementVisible and replace assert with verify.The test wont crash so we can see which element got wrong,which one was there.

Comment: I made lil changes in test code after click by adding `.waitForElementVisible('body', 5000,false)` and it never finds the body.

Comment: How about the others? I think you should ignore the 'body' tag, focus on some element which is more specific in the body (e.g : 'body > div[name="tabContainsiFrame"]'),it might help.

Comment: I've had difficulty identifying an iframe by the id and the name before. I would try '.frame(0)' because it has worked for me when name and id fail.

Comment: You should ignore the 'body' and focus on some element with specific selector ,e.g : `body > iframe[name=iframeone]` .Remember this: the 'body'  will present but not visible.